# How to add condition while uploading and downloading data in MS sync framework?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am working on Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1. I want to specify download condition for specific records from the server. how to specify the condition in  Sync Framework 2.1 while upload or download record from remotely.

Example :I have one main database. in that there are many tables.all user information will be stored in it.Client have application, where Client can stored data locally(in his local machine when Client offline).When hi want to store data in server , Client can used upload or download option.but while downloading, whole table is downloaded(from server containing other user information) in his machine. I want to allow Client to download his/her records only. so how i can specify the condition while user download or upload data in sync framework 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify a filter condition on what you want to sync.

check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928701.aspx